# polytope vs simplex

Tags: polytopes, simplex

It is stated that any polytope is an affine projection of a simplex. I do not quite understand this:

on the plane, a simplex has exactly 3 vertices, but let's consider a polytope 
$P=\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\}$ which has 4 vertices, which simplex an affine projetion of which is the polytope $P$?

I assume I am wrong, but where is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You need to be allowed to use simplices whose dimension is higher than your target polytope.  In the example you give, you would need a three-dimensional simplex (which has 4 vertices).